# Detecting bounced messages

Tags: php, email

I am working on a tool that will be sending bulk messages (not spam :) and I need to add a feature that will detect bounced messages. Is there a standard response associated with bounces? Would it be in the header of the body?

Answer (score 4):

This is typically achieved by setting the `Return-Path` header of your outgoing Mail to a unique Address for every recipient. For example, you could use `bounce+userid@example.com` if you have a unique userid identifing every recipient.

If the Mail gets bounces, you recieve it and parse the reciever (which will `bounce+userid@example.com`), you can then take appropriate actions.

Using the `+` syntax makes it possible to create a single mail-user (`bounces@example.com`) which recieves all bounces and still distinguish between the recipients.

Comment: Note that the userid should be encoded so that it's unguessable. Otherwise, anybody can deactivate your account simply by sending an email to bounce+theomega@example.com.

Comment: you shouldn't disable on one bounce, 3 is industry standard, the internet can be flaky.

Comment: Is + an allowed email character?

Comment: Oh, I don't intend to disable anything. I will will only mark bounces on each send.

Comment: you don't want to keep email addresses that always bounce, gets messy with a large db

Comment: @Alex: In fact you are right, you should not use the userid but instead a secret. A database matching between a random-char-sequence and the user and perhaps further information like a timestamp when the mail was sent would enable both, increased security and more features.

Comment: Very good! I have a script that I use in my other site that catches messages without mailboxes and splits the address by user. I suppose I'll just modify it to split bounce + USER. Yes, I can create a unique string for each address and each send. Is there a max char limit for the username part of an email? Any recommendations for unique string generator, fairly short and never repeating?

Comment: `md5sum(random())` should work. The RFC states "That limit is a maximum of 64 characters (octets) in the "local part" (before the "@")"

Comment: Note also that the key must be case insensitive, as you can't guarantee that a bouncing server will preserve what you send. I.e., you might set bounce-xyz@ and they might bounce to BOUNCE-XYZ@.

Answer (score 3):

You can not rely on either the headers or the body of the bounced message to be able to reliably identify the original recipient, especially if you want to automate the process. Even if you add your own custom headers, it's likely that the bouncing server will strip them when it sends notification back to you. And trying to parse text in the body of the message in order to pull out the recipient's email address can be dodgy at best, as there's no standard format and every bounce you get will be different. The only piece of information that will remain completely untouched in a bounce is the return path email address -- the address that your server advertises it wants bounces sent to. Thus, the only way to automate truly accurate bounce catching is to encode the recipient directly into the return path address itself.

This would typically be done by overriding your server's default return path address for each outgoing message, using a unique value per recipient, like bounce-XXXXX@yourdomain.com, where XXXXX is some encoded and/or obfuscated representation of the recipient's email address or some other internal identifier. This technique requires the use of an email server which can support this type of wild card catch-all address so that you don't have to set up a new bounce account for each email address you're sending to. Assuming that, you simply configure the server to dump all such bounce-* emails to your script, which needs only to decode the XXXXX in order to determine who the original recipient was.

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a max char restriction for XXXXX part?

Comment: I believe the local part (i.e., left of the @ sign) is limited to 64 characters.

Comment: I use addresses with a local part longer than 64, 65 to be exact; 32 char hash (^) 32 char hash, they have worked the last few years. Probably not a good idea, but there are the rfc's then there's 'reality'

Answer (score 1):

If your tool is going to be talking directly to the recipients' SMTP servers, it 
might be more advisable to check the error codes returned via the [SMTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) for 
4xx (temporary failure, e.g. "mailbox full") or 5xx (error, e.g. "no such user") 
responses.  Due to antispam/backscatter prevention mechanisms, you shouldn't rely on 
the recipient's server to reply with a non-delivery report whenever a message doesn't
go through.

Comment: I don't think I'll be connecting directly to SMTP... It'll be an email message to recipient...